# Which Serialization format supported by JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Which of the following Serialization format is/are supported by JSON ?

1. Recurring Structure
2. Invisible Structure
3. Function
4. None of the above

Comment: If this is homework, please use the `homework` tag. Whether it is or not, what's your take on the question?

Comment: That looks exactly like a test question just pasted in. Whether it is or not, you can't expect someone to answer it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Morning,

I just did a quick search on JSON recurring structure and came across the following powerpoint thats says:

```
JSON is not a general serialization format.
    No recursive/recurring structures
    No invisible structures
    No functions
```

The PDF file for this can be found [Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci571/Special/rwe_slides.pdf&ei=y1J0T5vbDYOg2AWT292CDw&usg=AFQjCNFDx0Q38JvDtGu7RQTB1hiJSUgHOw)

Comment: So you found the course material, that the op should have read...